# How do I load huge datasets of size 100GB to 1TB using Presto in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, presto

I want to create a spark dataframe using Presto. Currently, I am able to create a pandas dataframe from Presto using the following code:

```
def get_pandas_dataframe(self, hql, parameters=None):
        if not self.airflow_conn_reqd:
            import pandas
            cursor = self.presto_client.cursor()
            try:
                cursor.execute(self._strip_sql(hql), parameters)
                data = cursor.fetchall()
            except DatabaseError as e:
                raise PrestoException(self._get_pretty_exception_message(e))
            column_descriptions = cursor.description
            if data:
                df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
                df.columns = [c[0] for c in column_descriptions]
            else:
                df = pandas.DataFrame()
        else:
            df = self.get_pandas_df(hql)
        return (
            df.replace('', np.nan)
        )
```

I was thinking of creating a spark dataframe using something similar. But for that, I need to be sure that I can fetch all the data from Presto in my python code. I know I can directly do that using Spark but not sure with Presto-Python.

I have implemented the *spill-on-disk* on Presto and have made sure that the insertion is working fine. But since creating a dataframe would be an *in-memory* task, I am unclear as to how do I create a spark dataframe using Presto.

I have been thinking on the lines of creating a spark dataframe as usual and providing it the `data`. `data` comes from `cursor.fetchall()` but I am unaware of how Presto would perform at a huge scale.

In other/simpler words, how do I create a spark dataframe directly from presto?

Comment: use Spark(pyspark) / hadoop or other distributed system

Comment: @Asif
I know, I am willing to use spark and hence I wrote `pyspark` in the question. But how do I load from Presto? Are you saying that it won't be possible?

Comment: you could also try dask, I've not had a proper chance to use it on anything over ~10GB or so, but it's really good and v.similair to pandas so easy to pick up. check out their docs https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/

Comment: in In-memory task normal computers cant load 100GB data

Comment: @Asif I am talking about Presto loading this much of data. Can it do that?

Like I do in Spark, I create a `dataframe` from 100gb worth file and then I use it all along in my python code. 
Here, I want to load the 100gb from Presto in a variable `data` and create a spark dataframe. Or rather create spark dataframe directly from presto. How can I do that?

Comment: @Datanovice yeah I have worked with those but as of now, getting data via Presto in a spark dataframe is the requirement.